# How can I call a concrete Coffeecript function from html

Tags: javascript, html, coffeescript, craftyjs

I have an app that uses HTML, and Coffeescript in the frontend. I recently made it possible to change the language thanks to i18next.

Now I have some buttons that change my `window.userLang` to the different languages, but the user has to refresh some elements of the app to see it translated.

My problem comes because I need the translations made without refreshing the HTML.

In the app, I use Craftyjs, so what I need to know is how can (if possible) from HTML file, call a function that it's defined in Craftyjs.

The function I want to call is: `Crafty.scene("main")`.

Thanks all!

Comment: Coffeescript usually puts all your JS inside an anonymous function. If that's the problem, you should set `Crafty` to a global variable so that you can call it from everywhere.

Comment: Ok, If you answer with the same you just told me, I'll mark it as correct. Just tried what you said and it worked (It was so easy I couldn't see it U_U¿)

Comment: Reading the [Lexical Scope](http://coffeescript.org/#lexical-scope) section of the manual might be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a global name space defined above where your scripts are included. Then in your javascript you can define the functions you need as fields on that namespace.

```
<script>
  var MySweetWebApp = {};
</script>
<script src="..."></script>
```

... Inside JS file ....

```
MySweetWebApp.Crafty = { ... }
```

... From Anywhere ...

```
MySweetWebApp.Crafty.scene('main');
```